# Two foreign_key-based has_many associations with the same class—how can I have results of both associations returned on a single method call?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm building a small application in which Users can both send and receive Messages.  Each Message has a `sender_id` and a `recipient_id` (both contain User ids)

```
# Relevant lines of User model

has_many :sent_messages, :class_name => 'Message', :foreign_key => 'sender_id'
has_many :received_messages, :class_name => 'Message', :foreign_key => 'recipient_id'
```

What can I do in my User model to allow me to call `@user.all_messages`, and return both sent and received messages for that User?

(I'm using Rails 3.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible to do it with `has_many` associations. I will do it like this:

```
def all_messages
  Message.where("sender_id = ? OR recipient_id = ?", self.id, self.id)
end
```

This way, you can still append other filters to it.

Comment: This worked beautifully, thanks.  Handling the combination at the query level and returning the results as one unified set (which I can then sort / filter) is going to make this a very useful method for me going forward.

Answer (score 1):

```
def all_messages
   sent_messages + received_messages
end
```

Comment: I like the cleanliness of this code, and it certainly does work for returning all of both associations - though it (seemingly) does so by making two DB queries, then appending the second set of results to the first.  For my particular case, being able to further filter / order the results was important (for rendering in one continuous timeline), and I couldn't successfully call `@user.all_messages.order()' on this method.  Seemed more effective to handle the combination at the query level, and work on the results as a single returned set.

Comment: Also: I haven't tested this, but I'd be wary of the potential for duplicate items to be returned.  If, for instance, a User sent a Message to him/herself, I believe this would return that Message twice (once as a element of the sent_messages set, once as a element of the received_messages set).  Something to watch out for.